# Local storage only persists so far

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

Alright, this is really giving me a headache.  A while ago I made a simple game called "Crystal Collector", in which the user would be given a number (say 112) and a row of crystals with hidden values.  The player would try to match the number.  If he matched it, he would win, else he would lose.  Wins and losses would be tracked at the bottom.  They would not persist.  Here is the program: https://dennismarkham.github.io/week-4-game/

Now, I'm trying to spice up this game by adding persistent stat tracking with local storage.  That is to say, if the user refreshes or leaves the page, his wins and losses will remain the same.

Trying to implement this has had bizarre results.  It seems it does track, but only up to a point.  The console.logs for wins and losses can change from zero to one, but never track beyond that.  What's going on?

```
//sets a random goal number, set's player number
var goalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var playerNumber = 0;

//if there is no variable for wins or losses in local storage, it is set to zero
//else, the "wins" from local storage is achieved and put into the wins variable in
//the script
if (localStorage.getItem("wins") === null) {
  var wins = 0;
} else {
  var wins = localStorage.getItem("wins");
}


if (localStorage.getItem("wins") === null) {
  var losses = 0;
} else {
  var losses = localStorage.getItem("wins");
}

console.log("Wins:" + wins);
console.log("Losses:" + losses);




//gives a random value to blue, green, red, and purple
var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
var purple = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;


//assigns value to the gem pics based on above random numbers
$("#blueGem").attr("value", blue);
$("#greenGem").attr("value", green);
$("#redGem").attr("value", red);
$("#purpleGem").attr("value", purple);


//puts goal number variable in goal number box
$("#goalNumber").text(playerNumber);

//puts player number variable in player box
$("#playerNumber").text(goalNumber);

//puts wins in wins box (ccurrently at zero)
// $("#wins").text(wins);

// //puts losses in losses box
// $("#losses").text(losses);


//when you click one of the gems
$("img").click(function() {
  //playerNumber equals whatever it was before plus the value of the gem
  playerNumber = playerNumber + parseInt($(this).attr("value"));


  if (playerNumber == goalNumber) {
    //if the player number meets the goal number,
    //a non-existent varaible called wins is incremented.
    //see, how do I set up wins, without having it reset every refresh!?
    //So maybe check if there's already a value in local storage, and if not, 
    //assign it to
    //zero.
    //So at the top of the page "if wins in localstorage = true, wins = 
    //localStorage.getItem(wins)"
    //else, wins = 0.
    wins++;

    localStorage.setItem("wins", wins);

    var x = screen.width / 2 - 500 / 2;
    var y = screen.height / 2 - 350 / 2;
    window.open("win.html", "_blank", 'height=385,width=500,left=' + x + ',top=' + y);

    //if you win, goal number is reset, player number is reset, and so are gem 
    //values
    goalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 120) + 1;
    playerNumber = 0;


    blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    purple = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;

    $("#blueGem").attr("value", blue);
    $("#greenGem").attr("value", green);
    $("#redGem").attr("value", red);
    $("#purpleGem").attr("value", purple);

  }

  if (playerNumber > goalNumber) {
    losses++;

    localStorage.setItem("losses", losses);

    var x = screen.width / 2 - 500 / 2;
    var y = screen.height / 2 - 350 / 2;
    window.open("loss.html", "_blank", 'height=385,width=500,left=' + x + ',top=' + y);

    //if you lose, all those numbers are reset as well.     
    goalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    playerNumber = 0;

    blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    purple = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    $("#blueGem").attr("value", blue);
    $("#greenGem").attr("value", green);
    $("#redGem").attr("value", red);
    $("#purpleGem").attr("value", purple);
  }

  //this displays the playerNumber and goalNumber in their appropriate divs 
  //after each click
  $("#goalNumber").text(playerNumber);

  $("#playerNumber").text(goalNumber);

  // $("#wins").text(wins);

  // $("#losses").text(losses);






  //this extracts them from local storage to be printed.
  $("#wins").text(localStorage.getItem("wins"));

  $("#losses").text(localStorage.getItem("losses"));

  //now the problem is once you hit refresh, wins and losses go back to zero.  
  //Is that because
  //the computer starts reading from the top again?





});


$("button").click(function() {
  confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your stats?");

  if (confirm) {
    localStorage.clear();
  }
})
```

Comment: can you narrow your code down to the parts that are giving you errors? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not getting errors, and I'm not sure where it goes wrong.

Comment: You are alternating between using variables and `getItem()` . Stay consistent and store every update. In other words don't do `$("#wins").text(localStorage.getItem("wins"));` do `$("#wins").text(wins);`

Comment: Thanks charlietfl.  That...helped. It seems to work accept for the "Clear Stats" function.  That's still acting up, but my brain needs a break.

Answer (score 2):

localstorage save thing as a string, i think you should parse it
by the way the line

```
var losses = localStorage.getItem("wins");
```

seems a copy paste typo (it should be "losses")

```
if (localStorage.getItem("wins") === null) {
    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;
}
else 
{
    var wins = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("wins"));
    var losses = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("losses"));
}
```